# Wallpaper service crashing when integrated with another secton

Tags: android, android-service, live-wallpaper

Im creating a customised wallpaper service(LIVE WALLPAPER)...

I integrated it with another code section having 2 activity pages...but the Wallpaper is installing but crashing when the settings-activity page of the sane is loaded....

Is it a problem in the manifest????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you've set the SettingActivity correctly in xml

```
<wallpaper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:settingsActivity="fully.qualified.class.name.here"
/>
```

and make sure you're using right xml in the preference activity such as

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
```

live wallpapers sure can be tricky! :)

Good luck!

Comment: can Live Wallpapers be used along with any other sub applications?...I meant,can i install a Live Wallpaper along with any other application,programmatically?

Comment: Why not? I haven't myself tried it but there's nothing to stop you from doing so! :)

Comment: Thanks Ruuhkis...its really worked......Integration of 2 apps can be possible.......thanks for helping me to learn thatttttttt

Comment: Thanks for letting me be help. :)